# Checking if Firebase snapshot is equal to nil in Swift

Tags: json, swift, firebase, arc4random

I am trying to query Firebase to check if any user that has `waiting: "1"` and then when the snapshot is returned I want to see whether it is equal to nil. I have attempted to do this but the method I have used does not work and I only have some sort of out put if the snapshot is not equal to nil. I have added the code I currently have and the JSON text from Firebase.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import Spring

class GamesViewController: UIViewController {

let ref = Firebase(url: "https://123test123.firebaseio.com")
var activityIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()   

@IBAction func StartGamePressed(sender: AnyObject) {
    print("test1")
    var peopleWaiting: [String] = []

    let userRef = Firebase(url:"https://123test123.firebaseio.com/users")
    userRef.queryOrderedByChild("waiting").queryEqualToValue("1")
        .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            print(snapshot.key)
            if snapshot.key == nil {
                print("test2")
                let userData = ["waiting": "1"]
                let usersRef = self.ref.childByAppendingPath("users")
                let hopperRef = usersRef.childByAppendingPath("\(self.ref.authData.uid)")

                hopperRef.updateChildValues(userData, withCompletionBlock: {
                    (error:NSError?, ref:Firebase!) in
                    if (error != nil) {
                        print("Data could not be saved.")
                        self.displayAlert("Oops!", message: "We have been unable to get you into a game, check you have an internet conection. If this problem carries on contect support")
                    } else {
                        print("Data saved successfully!")
                        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                        let Home : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("continueToGame")
                        self.presentViewController(Home, animated: true, completion: nil)

                    }

                })


            } else {
                var randomUID: String
                peopleWaiting.append(snapshot.key)
                let randomIndex = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(peopleWaiting.count)))
                randomUID = peopleWaiting[randomIndex]
                print(randomUID)
                let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
                let Home : UIViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("continueToGame")
                self.presentViewController(Home, animated: true, completion: nil)

            }
        })
}

func displayAlert(title: String, message: String){

    let formEmpty = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    formEmpty.addAction((UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .Default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

    })))

    self.presentViewController(formEmpty, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func activityIndicatorFunction(){

    activityIndicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100))
    activityIndicator.backgroundColor = UIColor(red:0.16, green:0.17, blue:0.21, alpha:1)
    activityIndicator.layer.cornerRadius = 6
    activityIndicator.center = self.view.center
    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge
    view.addSubview(activityIndicator)
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().beginIgnoringInteractionEvents()

}


}
```

JSON Data:

```
{
"68e42b7f-aea5-4c3f-b655-51a99cb05bb0" : {
  "email" : "test1@test1.com",
  "username" : "test1",
  "waiting" : "0"
},
"8503d5a8-fc4a-492b-9883-ec3664898b4f" : {
  "email" : "test2@test2.com",
  "username" : "test2",
  "waiting" : "0"
}
}
```

Comment: Likely answer below. But please read about [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) (because I think your question might have been "how do I detect if a certain child exists?") and about how to construct a [minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you take care of both, it'll be much easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are a few things going on here, but the most important one is that you cannot test for the existence of children with `.ChildAdded`. That makes sense if you think about it: the `.ChildAdded` event is raised when a child is added to the location. If no child is added, the event won't be raised.

So if you want to test if a child exists at a location, you need to use `.Value`. Once you do that, there are various way to detect existence. Here's one:

```
ref.queryOrderedByChild("waiting").queryEqualToValue("1")
   .observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
       print(snapshot.value)
       if !snapshot.exists() {
           print("test2")
       }
   });
```

Answer (score 4):

Check for NSNull. This is the code for observing a node. Queries work much the same way.

Here's a complete and tested app. To use, change the string 'existing' to some path you know exists, like your users path and the 'notexisting' to some path that does not exist

```
    let myRootRef = Firebase(url:"https://your-app.firebaseio.com")
    let existingRef = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("existing")
    let notExistingRef = myRootRef.childByAppendingPath("notexisting")

    existingRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            print("This path was null!")
        } else {
            print("This path exists")
        }

    })

    notExistingRef.observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in

        if snapshot.value is NSNull {
            print("This path was null!")
        } else {
            print("This path exists")
        }

    })
```

Please note that by using .Value, there will be a guaranteed a return result and the block will always fire. If your code used .ChildAdded then the block will only fire when a child exists.

Also, check to make sure of how your data appears in firebase.

```
users
   user_0
     waiting: 1
```

if different than

```
users
   user_0
     waiting: "1"
```

Note that "1" is not the same as 1.

Comment: It does for sure work! I updated my answer with a complete and tested copy and pasted app I just wrote. If your code is not working then there is something else wrong - NSNull is the way to go!

Comment: Well all I know is that mine does not seem to be working, although the query you are using is different to mine... could that be making a difference? @Jay

Comment: If your reference or query is malformed or the App is not set up correctly, it could cause all kinds of issues. I would suggest copy and pasting your code as a test method and remove everything but the bare necessities and step through your code to see where it's not working.

Comment: I know the query I am using is working fine because if there is a result for the query to return then it does and the code works perfectly, but if there is not nothing happens... @Jay

Comment: @Jay "I believe that Firebase transactions could return a nil snapshot" We don't pass a snapshot into the transaction block, but the current value. That current value could indeed be null. But you're not using transactions here, so it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I don't think `nil` vs `NSNull` is the important part here. The problem in OP is that it's using `.ChildAdded`, which will only fire *when* a child exists. Your approach using `.Value` is the correct one for this use-case

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yes! You have the correct answer. I will leave mine for the NSNull check code example as they go hand-in-hand.

Comment: @Jay how can I use the logical NOT operator in this if statement? `if snapshot.value is NSNull`. I would like to write `if snapshot.value !== NSNull { //}` , but it does not compile. Thanks

Comment: @bibscy try *if !(snapshot.value is NSNull)*

Comment: @Jay could you please help me out with this?
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013963